# GCP functions http trigger returns: 600 - Callback not callable

Tags: google-cloud-functions, http-error

I have a POST request that is sent to an HTTP triggered GCP functions. It works fine most of the time but sometimes I get a `600 - Callback not callable` answer.

I googled the code error and couldn't find anything on this.

Did anyone encountered a similar situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace? Also a snippet code of what you are doing, the content of the request, etc.